# MongoDB: Can I use a created ObjectId before saving my document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

Using `mongoose` on node.js:

Can I access the `_id` field on a model *before* it has been saved to the database and be sure that the ID will not change?

For example, I would like to do the following:

```
var model = new mongoose.model('MyModel');
someOtherObject.myModelId = String(model._id);

// Some more code...

model.save(...);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mongoose, `_id` values must always be assigned client-side as [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-open) indicate that:

> Mongoose forces the db option `forceServerObjectId` false and cannot be overridden.

So the `model._id` value you get in the first line of your code will not be changed unless you do it in your own code before calling `model.save`.